# Is it better to install a nuget package per project, or globally for the whole solution?

Tags: .net, .net-core, compilation, nuget, nuget-package

When installing a nuget package, is there any decrease in compilation time/performance from installing it globally for the entire solution?

For example, say I need Newtonsoft.Json for a particular task in one project. The other projects currently don't need it, but there's a chance they will in the future.

Is there any downside to installing it in all projects in the solution at the start? Or is it better to install it only in the projects I need it, and add it to others later?

Comment: which are the benefits of intalling packages in projects that don't need them? )

Comment: @devcrp a colleague said it saved time - if we will probably need json serialization in many projects, just install it everywhere once. It is cleaner to install only the project you need, but are there any disadvantages to installing it in many?

Comment: @TomDane the only advantage would be to "save time" but this is not the case for common nuget packages. Intellisence in VS is advanced enough to identify classes and suggest to install nuget packages, and it works for common serialization libraries, because I have used it myself. On the contrary you can see a list of arguments why it is better to load packages per project in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to install the nugets in a targeted way, only in the projects that need to be used.

Reasons:

1. You load the projects with functionality that is not needed.
2. Add extra dlls in your publish folder and increase its size.
3. It might be misleading for the next developer looking at your code.